# Detecting when Workbox precaching has completed

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I need to have an event or plugin to know that precache process is successfully finished inside of the service worker.

I know how accomplish it natively

```
self.serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', function() {
   if (this.state === 'installed') {
     ...
   }
});
```

but how to with workbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workbox precaching also takes place during the `install` event, so you could listen for a similar state change.

Additionally, if you want more fine-grained reporting, you could use a [Workbox plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins) inside of your service worker that then called `postMessage()` to open clients reporting back the status (either when everything is complete, or after each response is cached):

```js
import {addPlugins, precacheAndRoute} from '../../packages/workbox-precaching';

const manifest = self.__WB_MANIFEST || [];
const manifestSize = manifest.length;
let precacheCount = 0;

async function sendToClients(message) {
  const clients = await self.Clients.matchAll();
  for (const client of clients) {
    client.postMessage(message);
  }
}

const handlerDidComplete = async ({request, error, event}) => {
  if (event.type === 'install') {
    if (error) {
      sendToClients(`Error while precaching ${request.url}: ${error}`);
    } else {
      precacheCount++;
      if (precacheCount >= manifestSize) {
        sendToClients(`Finished precaching ${manifestSize} entries.`);
      }
    }
  }
};

addPlugins([{handlerDidComplete}]);
precacheAndRoute(manifest);
```

You'd then listen for these messages in your client pages using `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', () => {...})`.

Again, this is optional, as you can just rely on the built-in APIs for listening to service worker lifecycle changes, even when you're using Workbox.

Comment: unfortunately the code will be called every time when handlerDidComplete is called and conditionals are true, but we need it to be called once after full service worker installation!

Comment: :-/ Sorry, that was the same issue as https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2878#issuecomment-939088750 I've updated the code snippet to explicitly check for `InstallEvent`. But like I said, you can also just listen for the service worker lifecycle events.

Comment: I can't just listen for the service worker lifecycle events on WebKit - it does not contain the property `self.serviceWorker` - so there is no any chance to get `installed` state of a new service worker instance (

Comment: I was referring to listening to the service worker lifecycle events in the `window` context, where `self` would be set to the `WindowGlobalScope`. Apologies if I'm missing something, but I'm not aware of any browsers where `self.serviceWorker` is set in the `window` context.

Comment: Can't find `InstallEvent` definition (

Comment: `self.serviceWorker` was intended in the context of use in the service-worker code, not in app code

Comment: Safari apparently doesn't have a definition of InstallEvent in the ServiceWorkerGlobalScope. I've switched the code sample to check `event.type === 'install'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239462/discussion-between-vadim-and-jeff-posnick).